# Several css per one uiBinder

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I wan't use several css files in one uibinder, like

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
         xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>

<ui:style magic="first" src="first.css"/>
<ui:style magic="second" src="second.css"/>

<g:Label styleName="{first.foo}">aaa</g:Label>
<g:Label styleName="{second.foo}">bbb</g:Label>
<g:Label styleName="{first.bar}">ccc</g:Label>
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use different `field` properties for each of the styles:

```
<ui:style field="first" src="first.css"/>
<ui:style field="second" src="second.css"/>
```